# How can I bind to a null value inside a template in a Universal Windows App?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

---

**Before you answer, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855369/why-is-xnull-no-longer-a-valid-value-in-a-style-setter-in-uwp).**

*Getting an answer for that first may resolve the issue below.*

---

This is a problem that just started with Windows 10 (Universal Apps). In Windows 8.1, and every other XAML technology, this technique worked flawlessly. Here's the setup in a blank universal app project:

**1. Static class with Attached Property**

Create a class that houses an attached property of type `Brush`. Put this anywhere in the project.

```
public static class MySettings
{
    public static Brush GetAccentBrush(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (Brush)d.GetValue(AccentBrushProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAccentBrush(DependencyObject d, Brush value)
    {
        d.SetValue(AccentBrushProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AccentBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AccentBrush",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(MySettings),
        null
        );
}
```

**2. Add a control to your MainPage.xaml using attached property**

In the main page, add a `ContentControl` with a custom template that has a `Grid` with its background color set to the accent brush. The accent brush is set in a style.

```
<Page x:Class="UniversalTest.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:local="using:UniversalTest"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyControl"
               TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="local:MySettings.AccentBrush"
                    Value="Green" /> <!-- Setting value here -->
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyControl}">
            <ContentControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding local:MySettings.AccentBrush}"> <!-- Using value here -->
                        <TextBlock Text="Howdy World!" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Template>
        </ContentControl>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

If you run the app now, it will show up with a green background. Everything works. However, if you set the value as `{x:Null}`, it throws an exception.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyControl"
            TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="local:MySettings.AccentBrush"
                Value="{x:Null}" /> <!-- Null value here -->
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Would anyone like to take a shot at this?

Comment: How about trying `Brush?` instead of `Brush`.

Comment: `Brush` is a class. `Nullable<T>` is only applicable to structs.

Comment: Why would you like to set the value as null?

Comment: The example above is part of a bigger issue. We try to reuse style as much as possible for a cleaner look n' feel. Some styles may have this value set to a real brush, while inheritors may disable it using `{x:Null}`.

Comment: Hey Laith, good question! :p

Comment: Btw, this `<Setter Property="local:MySettings.AccentBrush" Value="" />` works during run-time, the designer will complain though.

Comment: Nice one @JustinXL! But this provokes my OCD :D

Comment: Could you keep your Binding as-is, and just add a **TargetNullValue**? (this works on regular bindings, not sure about templatebinding or using with a Brush) `<Grid Background="{TemplateBinding local:MySettings.AccentBrush, TargetNullValue='Red'}">`

Comment: @Musters, no. The point is we want a null brush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, this issue appears to have been fixed. My project references Universal Windows version 10.0.10240.0. Setting the brush to {x:Null} as described by the original poster works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fake attached property :

```
    public static Brush GetNullAccentBrush(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (Brush)d.GetValue(NullAccentBrushProperty);
    }

    public static void SetNullAccentBrush(DependencyObject d, Brush value)
    {
        d.SetValue(NullAccentBrushProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NullAccentBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "NullAccentBrush",
        typeof(SolidColorBrush),
        typeof(MySettings),
        null
        );
```

And bind your property setter :

```
<Setter Property="local:MySettings.AccentBrush"
        Value="{Binding local:MySettings.NullAccentBrush}" />
```

The grid Background is null (even if there is no real binding on NullAccentBrush...).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this code works, in resource file

```
<Color x:Key="BgNull"></Color>
```

then in your style use that link to BgNull

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BgNull}"/>
```