# Why is {x:Null} no longer a valid value in a Style Setter in UWP?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

A follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818652/how-can-i-bind-to-a-null-value-inside-a-template-in-a-universal-windows-app), why is `{x:Null}` no longer a valid option for `Setter.Value`?

Put this code in a resource dictionary in your UWP app:

```
<Style x:Key="MyList"
        TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="Transitions" 
            Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>
```

And use it in any `ListView`:

```
<ListView Style="{StaticResource MyList}"/>
```

Your app will crash. A nasty crash as well, the kind that takes down the app without breaking properly in your debugger.

Also, the designer complains with a Catastrophic failure:

[image]

I know that setting values to `{x:Null}` is valid. If you set the `<ListView Transitions="{x:Null}"/>` directly, then it works fine... as expected.

So... what happened with style setters? ... Care to explain, Microsoft? Is there at least an alternate method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really a weird behavior and overall because as you explained setting directly to null works and with the style does not. The only alternative I found is just set a clear transitioncollection:

```
<Page.Resources>
<Style x:Key="MyList" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="Transitions" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection></TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>
```

I set the example of the DataContext that can be set to null, it says the same error but compiles and works.

I know it is not the best solution but it is a workaround to have a clear transitioncollection.

Comment: It looks like this is the only way. Hopefully MS will fix this in the future. Thanks Juan.

Answer (score 0):

[in this quiestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818652/how-can-i-bind-to-a-null-value-inside-a-template-in-a-universal-windows-app/39988478#39988478)
null-value-inside-a-template
[i've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988478/7004530) and you can find more answers

```
<Color x:Key="BgNull"></Color>
<Style x:Key="L2" TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BgNull}"/>
</Style>
```